# How can a container be added to show form contents?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to show form contents on a div which is supposed to be added with `.after()` property after pressing submit button.

Problem 1:
I have not validate form yet so when I press submit button the div is not added.. Why?. How will it work?

Problem 2:
After validation how to write elements of form onto div?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>prepend demo</title>
        <style>
            #PostDiv{
                position:relative; 
                top:2%; 
                left:30%;
                height:500px;
                width:600px;
                border:1px solid black;
                display:none;
            }
            #textField{
                position:absolute;
                left:20%;
                top:5%;
                height:25px;
                width:400px
            }
            #textArea{
                position:absolute;
                left:20%;
                top:30%;
                width:400px;
            }
            #addBut{
                position:absolute;
                display: block;
                padding: 3px 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
                top:75%;
                left:40%;
                height:8%;
                width:20%;
                font-size:150%;
            }
            #postAd{
                position:absolute;
                left:94%;
                top:0%;
            }   

            .content{
                position:relative;
                background-color: white;
                width: 500px;
                height:350px;
                padding: 25px;
                border: 5px solid black;
                display:block;
                margin-left:auto; 
                margin-right:auto;
                top:200px; 
                z-index:99999;
            }
            </style>
            <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div id="PostDiv">
                <label style="position:absolute;font-size:160%;top:5%; 
                left:8%;" for=textField">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="textField">
                <label style="position:absolute;font-size:160%;top:20%; 
                left:8%;" for="description">Description: </label>
                <textarea id="textArea" rows="12"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="addBut" value="Submit">//this is submit button
            </div>
        </form>

        <input type="button" id="postAd" value="Post an ad">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#postAd").click(function(){
                    $("#PostDiv").show();
                });
                var count=0;
                $("#‎addBut").click(function(){
                    $("#PostDiv").remove();
                    $('body').after('<div class="content" id="first'+count+'"></div>'); //This is div which is supposed to be added after pressing submit button
                    count++;
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Note:
When you run the code, you will see a button (Post an ad). After pressing it you will see form which is not validated yet. When you press submit button form will disappear and a div should be created which is not being created with `.after()` property. I am new in jquery can anyone please tell me that why submit button is not working?

Comment: you need to get a better code editor. There is some charecter in `$("‪#addBut‬")` in your code.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Some Charecter mean?

Comment: like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/iBmwy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with it working   https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/mp8Ltgxt/2/

As far as getting it to submit the form, you could call a function inside the click method that sends an ajax post, or whatever you intend to do in your submit. Also, you should look into separating your CSS and JS into separate files, and especially getting rid of all that inline CSS styling. It makes it hard to maintain, and hard for us to read.

HTML

```
<button type='button' id='show'>Place Ad</button>
<div id='container'>
    <p>
        <label>Title:</label>
    </p>
    <input type='text' id='txtTitle' />
    <p>
        <label>Description:</label>
    </p>
    <textarea id='txtDescription'></textarea>
    <button type='submit' id='submit'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    text-align:center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
}
.content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS

```
var count = 0;
$('#show').click(function () {
    $('#container').toggle();
    $('.content').hide();
});
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    $('#container').toggle();
    $('body').after('<div class="content" id="first' + count + '"></div>');

    $('.content').show();
    count++;
});
```

Comment: After that can I add form elements to div easily? which function should I use

Comment: Add form elements to the div you create when pressing submit?

Comment: If you want to get the value from the form you just submit, yes. In your submit on click, just declare a variable and set it to $('#id').val(). Then you can add any element inside the append string and use the variable to give it a value.  Check this updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/mp8Ltgxt/3/

Comment: Ok.. Thank you Sir...! You have saved my a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the form from being submitted when the submit button is clicked.

```
$("#addBut").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Then how form will be submitted?

Comment: In your case, you can't since you have removed the form. You need to hide the form, and submit it using $("form").submit(), it is better to give your form an id and you can use $("#id").submit()

Comment: Can we print individual elements of form using .val() and .text()